# How can I get key not value, from React on change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show the title in the dropdown but be able to store the id of the title selected. Is there a way to be able to get the item.key (onChange)?

```
data = [
{"id": "1", "title": "First title"},
{"id": "2", "title": "Second title"},
{"id": "3", "title": "Third title"}
]
```

```
return (
        <div>
        <label>Select Question
        <select onChange={(e) => {
            setQuestionId(e.target.key);
        }}>
        {data.map(item => (
            <option id={item.id} value={item.title}>
                {item.title}
            </option>
        ))}
        </select>
        </label>
        <p>{question_id}</p>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Why not leave the title as what's displayed but make the id the value?

Comment: Consider making the `value={item.id}` and then use `e.target.value`

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, I didn't think of that. Thanks <3